# How to set dynamic UICollectionViewCell Spacing

Tags: ios, ios8, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having an issue trying to set the celling spacing within my collection view. Everything looks good on the iPhone 5 but when I run it on the 6 and 6 plus the cell spacing drastically increases. I set the min spacing to 10 but that seem not to help. The first image is what I'm trying to achieve across all devices. Pictures following after is what I'm actually getting:

[image: iPhone 5]

[image: iPhone 6]

[image: iPhone 6 plus]

Here's a picture of my settings in IB:

[image: IB Settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you meant to set the `minimumInteritemSpacing` (minimum spacing to use between items in the same row).

Either way, the minimum spacing is the smallest spacing you'd accept, not the exact spacing you want.  A space of 100 is still valid since it's greater than a minimum of 10.

The real issue is the cell size, which you've fixed at 150x200.  If you want your cells to adjust their width, you'll need to calculate the flow layout's `itemSize` based on the view width.

- **If all your cells will be the same size**, you can set the flow layout's `itemSize` property:

  ```
  #define kCellsPerRow 2

  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
  CGFloat availableWidthForCells = CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (kCellsPerRow - 1);
  CGFloat cellWidth = availableWidthForCells / kCellsPerRow;
  flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, flowLayout.itemSize.height);
  ```
- **If you need to calculate per-cell sizes**, you can do it in the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate.

Recalculate the itemSize when the device orientation changes and update the layout:

- **Redraw layout without animation:**

  `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`
- **Animate layout changes:**

  `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil]`

Comment: If I use the itemSze property would that be the same as me setting a fixed width on the cell? I implemented the itemSize property in my view did load but got the same results. Not sure if I'm following correctly.

Comment: Appreciate your help, will test it out in a few.

Comment: I have a same problem but I am not working. I added in viewdidload.